# zsh: command not found: create

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm following this course on python and pandas and wanted to create a playground, but it keeps telling me "zsh: command not found: create"
FYI I have Anaconda installed

I tried ls command and other commands, it works fine. But not this one

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out somehow. Just relaunched Anaconda and the terminal
then did

```
conda create --name (name of the environment)
```

And it worked